# Searching text within a column and completely replace

Tags: r

Suppose i have a data frame containing two things payment and source of payment(listed under name)

```
df<-data.frame(payment=c(100,500,1000,300,200),name=c('xcv#$12 amazon as' , 'amazon inc.','FSaw alibaba','other company' , 'dasdas amazon'))


 payment             name
1     100          xcv#$12 amazon as
2     500          FSaw amazon inc.
3    1000          alibaba
4     300          other company 
5     200          dasdas amazon
```

Suppose data is huge and i just want to do this like replace the text that contain amazon in it with amazon inc. and remove all other things.
mydesired output

```
 payment             name
1     100          amazon inc.
2     500          amazon inc.
3    1000          alibaba
4     300          other company 
5     200          amazon inc.
```

I want to replace all text carrying amazon inside it with amazon inc. how can i do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
df$name[grepl("amazon",df$name)] <- "amazon inc."
```

or, as suggested by @DavidArenburg:

```
df$name[grepl("amazon",df$name, fixed=TRUE)] <- "amazon inc."
```

Comment: Thanks a  lot  .It works like charm for the above problem but not working with real data .It is saying invalid factor level , NA generated. Any suggestion

Comment: @learner This suggests two things: (a) The data in the column is stored as factors and (b) there is no entry "amazon inc." in the column "name" of the original data.frame. Maybe you could try again after applying `df$name <- as.character(df$name)` to the original data.frame.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked. now there is one more problem . To tackle the lower and upper case letter and combination of both I used ignore.case=TRUE as suggested in the description of the function but it is just giving me  a warning and doing nothing with the data . Need suggestion on this also. Can't i do it in a single shot ?

Comment: @learner I think that the options `fixed=TRUE` and `ignore.case=TRUE` are not compatible. Probably `df$name[grepl("amazon", df$name, ignore.case=TRUE)] <- "amazon inc."` will work.

Comment: can't i equate multiple values equal to one into a single stroke in  regex ? any way to do that ? 
Suppose i want to replace whenever i see 'amazon' and 'alibaba' to 'e-commerce company' into a single command line . I tired or sign '|' but R is giving me an error. any other way of doing this ?

Comment: A quick fix could be `df$name[grepl("alibaba", df$name, ignore.case = TRUE) | grepl("amazon", df$name, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "e-commerce company"` but there are certainly more elegant ways. I think that this could be addressed better in a separate question.

Comment: @RHerel thank you. find one more way. df$name[grepl('alibaba | amazon ",df$name,i gnore.case = TRUE)]<-'e-commerce company' works better