# Dataframe manipulation: How to replace artifacts within a text-column?

Tags: r

The goal is to find & replace artifacts from pdf-parsing in a text-column named "text" within a dataframe for every row.

`"<U+FB01>"` is to be replaced with `"fi"` &
`"<U+FB02>"` is to be replaced with `"fl"`

`df<-data.frame(text=c('Das neue P<U+FB02>ege<U+FB01>nanzierungsgesetz','Die Kon<U+FB02>ikte zwischen Spitalrat und','Im neuen Spital<U+FB01>nanzierungsgesetz, welches'))`

should be:

`df2<-data.frame(text=c('Das neue Pflegefinanzierungsgesetz','Die Konflikte zwischen Spitalrat und','Im neuen Spitalfinanzierungsgesetz, welches'))`

Screenshot of the dataframe: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxpDu.png

Closest I could find to a solution (but can't get it to work): [Searching text within a column and completely replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260249/searching-text-within-a-column-and-completely-replace)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please include a representative & minimal text plus code example. A screenshot is not helpful because we can't copy & paste data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsub`:

```
df <- data.frame(text=c('acbd<U+FB01>efg', 'abc<U+FB01> efg <U+FB02>', 'ab cd'),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
df

#                      text
#1          acbd<U+FB01>efg
#2 abc<U+FB01> efg <U+FB02>
#3                    ab cd

df$text <- gsub('<U\\+FB01>', 'fi', df$text)
df$text <- gsub('<U\\+FB02>', 'fl', df$text)
df

#          text
#1    acbdfiefg
#2 abcfi efg fl
#3        ab cd
```

Note that `\\` escapes the `+` character that has a special meaning within the regex.

Comment: Tried `for (i in 1:length(texte$text)) {
  texte$text[i] <- gsub('<U\\+FB01>', 'fi', texte$text[i])
  print(i)
}` and it didn't grab the artifacts. Dataframe was built with `stringsAsFactors = F`.

Comment: Tried your exact code with my texts. `df <- data.frame(text=texte$text,
                 stringsAsFactors = F) df$text <- gsub('<U\\+FB01>', 'fi', df$text)` also no effect